# Invariant Violation:"verticalAlign" is not a valid style property

Tags: css, vue.js, vue-native

I try to put the text in the middle of button but whenever i use `vertical-align: middle` i will get the error. So whats the problem?

```
  <view>
        <touchable-opacity class="button"
            :on-press="onPressLearnMore"
          >
        <text class="loginText">login</text>
          </touchable-opacity>
        </view>
```

my css:

```
.loginText{
  color: white;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.button{
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #0B5376;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no vertical-align in Vue Native.

Use alignItems with flexbox instead:
https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/elements/layouts/flexbox-layout/

```
  style={{
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
  }}
```

Comment: hi bro, my question is about vue native, not react native

Comment: and if i use your code in my template it will give me an error: App.vue: Cannot read property 'attrsMap' of undefined

Comment: Flexbox is used there as well and the reason for the error is the same, I have updated the link.

Comment: I added your code into the `text` tag, now i getting `Invariant Violation: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component`

Comment: `<view>
        <touchable-opacity class="button" :on-press="login">
          <text style={{
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
  }} class="loginText">登入</text>
        </touchable-opacity>
      </view>`

Comment: All of these further issues are unrelated to your original issue, for which flexbox is the answer. Please mark as correct when you fix your other problems.